# Deleting bootstrap slider using jquery

Tags: jquery, slider

How can I delete a slider created as below,

```
var slider = new Slider('#brightness', {
});
```

Thanks,
Minu

Comment: The slider plugin  must have provided methods, search their docs

Comment: Read the docs: https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider There is a destroy method that removes the slider instance.

Answer (score 3):

You can remove it via calling its `destroy` method which will properly clean up and remove the slider instance as follows:

```
var slider = new Slider('#brightness', {
});

//delete the slider 
slider.destroy();
```